# How to close tabs when one is active on jquery?

Tags: jquery, tabs

Here is a tabs code when tabs don't deactived when one is active. I try to use it for another page and add deactivation for tabs when one is active, but get console error **$(...).parent(...).siblings(...).hasClass(...).each is not a function**.
I rarely work with jquery, please tell me how to do it right way.

```
var acc = $('.questions_item_title');
var accAnother = $('.page-another .questions_item_title');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            $(this).parent('.questions_item').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            $(this).parent('.questions_item').addClass('active')
            for (var j = 0; j < accAnother.length; j++) {
                $(this).parent('.questions_item').siblings().hasClass('active').removeClass('active');
            };
        }
    });
}

accAnother[0].parentElement.classList.add("active");
accAnother[0].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = accCredLine[0].nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
```

Comment: I think you might have to wrap it in an if statement or adjust code a bit.
```$(this).parent('.questions_item').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');```
Since i cannot find any ```$.each()``` here (where error message stops), it must be ```$.hasClass()``` that is causing the problems, since it returns a boolean and is usually used if if statements and the like

Comment: Thanks, this problem was caused by calling removeClass that returns object after calling hasClass function that returns boolean value.